# How to add title and customize x and y axis of a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, customization

```
ax.set(title="simple plot",
      xlabel="x-axis",
      ylabel="y-axis")

fig.savefig("image/sample-plot.png")
```

[simple plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaNij.png)

I checked matplotlib version to see if it's an old one.

Comment: So you checked your version... what version was it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
y_vals =[1,2,3,4,5]
x_label = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.ylabel("%")
plt.xlabel("months")
plt.xticks(x_label,["jan","feb","mars","apr","etc"])
plt.plot(x_label,y_vals)
plt.savefig("sample-plot.png")
plt.show()
```